# Xgboost, max number of cores

Tags: r, xgboost

I am running **XGboost in R on Windows Server 2008 R2.**

I have 4 Xeon E7 with 10 cores each. (80 threads total)

I run Xgboost with  `nthread = 80` but R uses only `40`. Does xgboost somehow reduces the number of threads, depending on the Input Data?

Does anyone had similar problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think it doesn't work with the hyperthreading x2 thread

from xgboost site
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/cb4de521c13f3d2269c20252a393cfd33f4a1ae3/doc/tutorials/external_memory.rst

Performance Note

the parameter nthread should be set to number of real cores
     Most modern CPU offer hyperthreading, which means you can have a 4 core cpu with 8 threads
        Set nthread to be 4 for maximum performance in such case

Comment: Thank you. Is there any reason xgboost does not support hyperthreading?

Comment: your link is dead!

Comment: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/cb4de521c13f3d2269c20252a393cfd33f4a1ae3/doc/tutorials/external_memory.rst